# Appium - SendKeys not working in iOS real device

Tags: ios, selenium, automation, appium

Here is my code to send keys to textfield:

```
private IOSDriver<IOSElement> appleDriver;
RemoteWebElement remoteWebElement = new RemoteWebElement();
remoteWebElement.setId(elementId);
remoteWebElement.setParent(appleDriver);
remoteWebElement.sendKeys("text");
```

When debugging, I received null pointer exception. I am using appium java client 6.0.0 and Selenium 3.12.0